Could the characterization in terms of full idempotents be used to show that Morita equivalence is symmetric??
The existence of $m$ and $f$ realizing the inverse Morita equivalence $R \cong fM_m(S)f$ follows from the fact that the given isomorphism $S \cong eM_n(R)e$ arises from a projective generator that induces an equivalence of module categories. By choosing the other projective generator defining the inverse equivalence (namely, $M_n(R)e$ considered as an $S$-module), one can identify $R$ with the endomorphism ring of that module. Morita theory then guarantees that this endomorphism ring can be expressed as $fM_m(S)f$ for a suitable positive integer $m$ and a full idempotent $f \in M_m(S)$. While such a construction is always possible, there is no reason to expect that applying the same process twice will necessarily yield the same pair $(n,e)$.
Morita equivalences establish a fundamental connection between rings by identifying their module categories. Given a ring $R$, a Morita equivalent ring $S$ is one for which there exists an equivalence of categories:
$$
R\text{-Mod} \simeq S\text{-Mod}.
$$
Such equivalences are described by pairs of bimodules that act as "mutually inverse" functors. Specifically, a Morita equivalence is determined by a projective generator. If $S$ is Morita equivalent to $R$, there exists a right $R$-module $P$ such that $S \cong \operatorname{End}_R(P)$. The module $P$ is a projective generator in $R\text{-Mod}$, and this ring isomorphism induces the equivalence by mapping an $R$-module $M$ to $\operatorname{Hom}_R(P,M)$, an $S$-module.
In the given scenario, we begin with an isomorphism:
$$
S \cong eM_n(R)e
$$
for a positive integer $n$ and an idempotent $e \in M_n(R)$ such that $M_n(R)eM_n(R) = M_n(R)$ (i.e., $e$ is a full idempotent). Here, the module $P = eM_n(R)$ plays the role of the projective generator for $R\text{-Mod}$, and $S \cong \operatorname{End}_R(P)$.
To demonstrate the symmetry and find a corresponding $f \in M_m(S)$ and $m$ such that $R \cong fM_m(S)f$, we need to consider the inverse equivalence of categories. The equivalence $R\text{-Mod} \simeq S\text{-Mod}$ is provided by two functors:

$F: R\text{-Mod} \to S\text{-Mod}$ given by $F(M) = eM_n(R) \otimes_R M  \cong \operatorname{Hom}_R(P,R) \otimes_R M$.
Its quasi-inverse $G: S\text{-Mod} \to R\text{-Mod}$.

To construct $G$, we examine the bimodule $Q = M_n(R)e$, which is naturally an $S$-$R$-bimodule because $S \cong eM_n(R)e$. Then $G(N) = Q \otimes_S N$ defines the inverse functor. The module $Q = M_n(R)e$ serves as a projective generator in $S$-Mod, which yields:
$$
R \cong \operatorname{End}_S(Q).
$$
Morita theory guarantees that $\operatorname{End}_S(Q)$ is isomorphic to a matrix ring over $S$ "cut down" by a full idempotent. Specifically, there exists an integer $m$ and an idempotent $f \in M_m(S)$ such that
$$
R \cong fM_m(S)f.
$$
This establishes the symmetry: Starting from the pair $(n,e)$ that defines $S$ in terms of $R$, we obtain another pair $(m,f)$ that expresses $R$ in terms of $S$.
In particular, this construction is not canonical. Different choices along the way can lead to different $(m,f)$ pairs. Consequently, starting with $(n,e)$, moving to $S$, and then applying the inverse construction to return to an $R$-like form, will not necessarily result in the same $(n,e)$. This lack of uniqueness is a characteristic feature of Morita theory. While it provides a powerful way to classify rings up to module category equivalence, it does not produce a unique "canonical" representative.
Given $S \cong eM_n(R)e$, the module $Q=M_n(R)e$ over $S$ is formed. This $Q$ is a projective generator in $S\text{-Mod}$, which implies $R \cong \operatorname{End}_S(Q)$. Applying Morita's theorem again, we deduce that $\operatorname{End}_S(Q)$ is isomorphic to $fM_m(S)f$ for some $m$ and a full idempotent $f \in M_m(S)$. This illustrates the symmetry of Morita equivalence. However, because these constructions are non-unique, applying the process twice typically does not return the original pair $(n,e)$.
